# Open Source SIP Dialer in C#

Tags: c#, sip

Is there any Open Source Code availbale for makeing A SIP Dialer in C# or any other language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, take a look at [PJSIP](http://www.pjsip.org/). It is implemented in very portable C. But it also has a number of wrappers in other languages, like this [.NET wrapper](http://sipekphone.googlepages.com/pjsipwrapper).

PJSIP, or rather its UA (SIP Dialer) interface PJSUA is very easy to handle, and takes care of both signalling and media for you. Oh, and it's under GPL license.

Answer (score 3):

PjSIP and Sofiasip are two top SIP communication libraries to develop dialers of your choice, however there are already many dialers already developed.

Please check following [list](http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Projects_Using_PJSIP) of dialers developed over PJSIP sip stack, may someone from list fulfill all of your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

MySIPSwitch uses a C# SIP stack [mss source](http://mysipswitch.codeplex.com/). The media support in that stack is not complete but the SIP stack is pretty good. The stack is used to run the service by the same name [mss service](http://www.mysipswitch.com).